# CUDA C++: Call log() function on device

Tags: c++, cuda

I have the need to call `log()` function at the kernel side. How can I call an host function from device?
colpilers says

```
error: calling a __host__ function("std::log<unsigned short> ") from a __global__ function("my_kernel_function") is not allowed
```

Comment: "How can I call an host function from device?" <- You can't. However...

Comment: Generally, the over-loaded math functions on the device take `float` and `double` arguments, but not integer arguments. So convert your integer (here: `unsigned short`) to a `float` or `double` and call `log()` with that. I am a bit surprised the host compiler has an `unsigned short` overload of `log()`, is that a C++11 thing?